# Change specific tile image source in OpenLayers 5

Tags: openlayers, tiles

I defined a XYZ source and added to map

```
var source = new ol.source.XYZ({
  url: 'http://blabla.com/{x}/{y}/{z}.png',
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
})
```

During runtime I can access specific tile by

```
map.getLayers().getArray()[0].getSource().getTile(2,1,-3)
```

Now I want to change this tile image. I tried setting **src_** and **image_** properties but no change.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the solution.

Firstly change tile's src by calling

```
map.getLayers().getArray()[0].getSource().getTile(2,1,-3).image_.src="base64 or new url"
```

Then call `changed()` function on the tile

```
map.getLayers().getArray()[0].getSource().getTile(2,1,-3).changed()
```

After all to refresh this tile call `changed()` function on the source object

```
map.getLayers().getArray()[0].getSource().changed()
```